# Tweaking linux console: 1) display password 2) set background color

Tags: linux, passwords, colors, console, pam

I want to alter background color since very first lines of kernel output, remember that there was an ability to change colors with `echo`'ing some special character, but waiting for /etc/init.d/* is too long for me; however, if it is only the method available..

Also, want to de-secure the password input, using PAM:

login: user
password: ****** <- need to show asterisks indicating how much symbols got in.

Comment: 1. setterm seems to be not working.

Comment: This should be split into two separate questions.

Comment: Split? Only in case it gets edited to "how to enable framebuffer and make PAM authorize me through LDAP". This is not so specific. Just, "how do i alter my login prompt style and colors"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks complicated ...
Appart from adding stuff in /etc/issue which will just change the "text"above the login/password like here http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/TIP_Login_issue
It seems that you have to code (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/customizing-login-on-terminal-636960/)

Comment: I have modified /etc/issue, and use Qingy instead of getty to manage my login (e.g. to start X server's session or console by hotkey after password), but still don't know how (in which order) getty calls /bin/login (seems to be in sys-apps/shadow package). However, (thank to you), found, that GETPASS_ASTERISK option was dropped from shadow, so should somehow code it.. would look/code.